# How to remove Sunspot indexed data after removing model indexing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr, websolr

I'm using [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) with [Sunspot](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot) gem and [Websolr](https://www.websolr.com/) for Solr hosting. Let's say I have a Solr indexed ActiveRecord model like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text :name
  end
end
```

Now I want to remove indexing from this model, so I just remove this indexing code (searchable block). Will the indexed data be removed automatically from Solr? I assume not and that I need to remove/reindex in manually. I can reindex everything like this:

```
Sunspot.index
Sunspot.commit
```

But reindexing my whole database will be slow. Is there another - faster way to stop indexing 1 model? I don't see any interface in Websolr to look through and delete records from the index and I can't seem to find any information on how to remove models from indexing with Sunspot.

Comment: You can this by using `<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>` finally like `curl http://hostname:port/solr/update?commit=true -d '<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>'`, have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

> I can reindex everything like this:

No, you can't, if you need to reindex again then open Rails console by typing `rails c` and then

```
=> Model.index

# User Load (15.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 50]]
# [2018-02-27 18:45:04 +0600] Start Indexing
# D, [2018-02-27T18:45:05.439714 #15296] DEBUG -- :   SOLR Request (762.4ms)  [ path=update parameters={} ]
```

And for the removing indexed data then try to the following

```
curl http://localhost:8982/solr/default/update?commit=true -d '<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>'
```

Let's describe on the url part

- *`localhost`*: is the hostname.
- *`8982`*: port number where your Solr server running if you confusing what is your port number then open rails console and type this `puts Sunspot.config.inspect` it will show your port number.
- *`/solr/default/update`*: this is the path where your command execute.
- *`?commit=true -d`*: That is the instruction.
- *`'<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>'`*: that is the method.

I have found this [here](https://daniel.hepper.net/blog/2010/11/howto-clear-solr-index/) but it's not working for me because there are port number and path different, I have edited my own way and it's working perfectly.

I think it will help.